# AndEngine not displaying sprite

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to make a basic AndEngine game but the sprite doesn't appear. I don't get any errors.

I can't find the issue and neither can the guy who's helping me with this so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class Game extends BaseGameActivity implements SensorEventListener {

Scene scene;
protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas playerTexture;
private TextureRegion regionCell;
private Sprite sprCell;
private SensorManager sensorManager;

private float accellSpeedX, accellSpeedY;
private float sprX, sprY;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                    CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
    return options;
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    // BitmapTextureAtlas must be power of 2 for width and height.
    playerTexture = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(
            this.getTextureManager(), 256, 64);
    regionCell = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
            playerTexture, this.getAssets(), "player.png");
    playerTexture.load();

    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(this.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateSpritePosistion();
        }

        private void updateSpritePosistion() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (accellSpeedX != 0 || accellSpeedY != 0) {
                int tL = 0;
                int iL = 0;
                int rL = CAMERA_WIDTH - (int) sprCell.getWidth();
                int bL = CAMERA_HEIGHT - (int) sprCell.getHeight();

                if (sprX >= iL) {
                    sprX += accellSpeedX;
                } else {
                    sprX = iL;
                }
                if (sprX <= rL) {
                    sprX += accellSpeedX;
                } else {
                    sprX = rL;
                }
                if (sprY >= tL) {
                    sprY += accellSpeedY;
                } else {
                    sprY = tL;
                }
                if (sprY <= bL) {
                    sprY += accellSpeedY;
                } else {
                    sprY = bL;
                }
                if (sprX < iL) {
                    sprX = iL;
                } else if (sprX > rL) {
                    sprX = rL;
                }
                if (sprY < tL) {
                    sprY = tL;
                } else if (sprY > bL) {
                    sprY = bL;
                }

                sprCell.setPosition(sprX, sprY);

            }
        }
    });

    this.scene = new Scene();
    this.scene.setBackground(new Background(0, 122, 222));
    sprX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.regionCell.getWidth()) / 2;
    sprY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.regionCell.getHeight()) / 2;
    sprCell = new Sprite(sprX, sprY, regionCell,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    scene.attachChild(sprCell);
    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);

}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    synchronized (this) {
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accellSpeedX = (int) event.values[1];
            accellSpeedY = (int) event.values[0];
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do the image dimensions fit inside the Atlas?

Comment: @jmroyalty I would think so. The image is a power of two. If this isn't what you mean could you explain a bit more.

Comment: Have you done any debugging to make sure the variables (specifically your sprite variables) are what you think they are?

Comment: so what are the dimensions of "player.png"? and are they less than 256x64

Comment: regionCell.load() try this.it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this..I have tried it and solved the problem...  Just set & change the size of your image in mBitmapTextureAtlas and name of your image in mTextureRegion under onCreateResources...

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements
    SensorEventListener {

Scene scene;
private ITextureRegion mTextureRegion;
private BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;

protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas playerTexture;
private Sprite sprCell;
private SensorManager sensorManager;

private float accellSpeedX, accellSpeedY;
private float sprX, sprY;

Rectangle rect;
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                    CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
    return options;
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 100, 100);
    this.mTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "mo.png");

    try
    {
        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas
                .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                        0, 0, 0));
        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
    } 
    catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) 
    {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.scene = new Scene();
    this.scene.setBackground(new Background(0, 122, 222));

    sprX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    sprY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
    sprCell = new Sprite(sprX, sprY, mTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(sprCell);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(this.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateSpritePosistion();
        }

        private void updateSpritePosistion() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (accellSpeedX != 0 || accellSpeedY != 0) {
                int tL = 0;
                int iL = 0;
                int rL = CAMERA_WIDTH - (int) sprCell.getWidth();
                int bL = CAMERA_HEIGHT - (int) sprCell.getHeight();

                if (sprX >= iL) {
                    sprX += accellSpeedX;
                } else {
                    sprX = iL;
                }
                if (sprX <= rL) {
                    sprX += accellSpeedX;
                } else {
                    sprX = rL;
                }
                if (sprY >= tL) {
                    sprY += accellSpeedY;
                } else {
                    sprY = tL;
                }
                if (sprY <= bL) {
                    sprY += accellSpeedY;
                } else {
                    sprY = bL;
                }
                if (sprX < iL) {
                    sprX = iL;
                } else if (sprX > rL) {
                    sprX = rL;
                }
                if (sprY < tL) {
                    sprY = tL;
                } else if (sprY > bL) {
                    sprY = bL;
                }

                sprCell.setPosition(sprX, sprY);

            }
        }
    });


    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);

}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    synchronized (this) {
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accellSpeedX = (int) event.values[1];
            accellSpeedY = (int) event.values[0];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should load your textures before you create texture region from them.

Comment: This might be more helpful if you included an example of how to load said textures.